# MVC5 Identity with DI (Removing Service Locator anti-pattern)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to remove the Service Locator Anti Pattern that comes by default with a new MVC5 project.  I am attempting to implement DI instead using Ninject.  I have come upon the following guide which is meant for unity, not an MVC5 application.

http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

From what I can tell, there is not too much difference in code between that article and a new MVC5 application.  However there is one thing that I cannot seem to figure out what to do with.

In the article I provided above exists the following method

```
private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
}
```

I am trying to understand what this container is and what I would register my classes to in MVC5.  Do I need to register my classes to some container to begin with?  Still learning here and I'm quite new to MVC5 and Identity so any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container contains configuration settings for each abstraction and its implementation. The `container` is used to create dependencies and inject them automatically when required. Whenever there is a need of instance of an abstraction, the container provides that to the requester. It automatically creates objects based on request and inject them when required. The container helps to manage dependencies with in the application in a simple and easy way.